# Finding derivative of a product

Tags: calculus, derivatives

I am wondering if there is a way to find the derivative of the following without multiplying the whole thing out and then finding the derivative with respect to $W$

$$W(1-W)(-w+e+\theta W)$$

Comment: You could use the product rule. However, multiplying it out seems simpler.

Comment: could you show how me how to use the product rule for this?

Comment: $$\frac{d}{dx} \left[f(x)g(x)h(x)\right] = \frac{df}{dx}gh + f\frac{dg}{dx}h + fg\frac{dh}{dx}$$

Answer (score 0):

$$\frac d{dW}W(1-W)(-w+e+\theta W)\\=(1-W)(-w+e+\theta W)-W(-w+e+\theta W)+W(1-W)\theta$$ But to simplify this you would probably want to multiply it out, so there doesn't seem much point in doing it in this way.